# Wrong output in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, if-statement, output, write-host

```
$status_message = Get-HPiLoFirmwareversion -Server 172.16.2.210 -Username administrator -Password xxxx -DisableCertificateAuthentication -WarningAction SilentlyContinue |
                  Select-Object -Property STATUS_MESSAGE

if ($status_message -eq '@{STATUS_MESSAGE=OK}') {
    Write-Host "Status OK"
    exit 0
} else {
    Write-Host "error"
    exit 0
}

Write-Host $status_message
```

but I'm getting the following output:

```
@{STATUS_MESSAGE=OK}
```

instead of just "OK".

```
$status_message = Get-HPiLoFirmwareversion -Server 172.16.2.210 -Username administrator -Password xxxxx -DisableCertificateAuthentication -WarningAction SilentlyContinue

Write-Host $status_message
```

gives:

```
IP                   : 172.16.2.210
HOSTNAME             : 
STATUS_TYPE          : OK
STATUS_MESSAGE       : OK
FIRMWARE_DATE        : Sep 23 2016
FIRMWARE_VERSION     : 2.50
LICENSE_TYPE         : iLO Advanced
MANAGEMENT_PROCESSOR : iLO4
```

It looks like the HP iLO cmdlet is possibly using a `Write-Host` to output their error message and that may be the issue.

Comment: Maybe $status_message contains all the output including, IP, HOSTNAME etc ?

Comment: use `$status_message.status_message` to make it output only "OK"

Comment: Thanks, michael solution is the one

Comment: Change `| Select-Object -Property STATUS_MESSAGE` -> `| Select-Object -ExpandProperty STATUS_MESSAGE`

Comment: mathias has a better solution do thx